# Blurred effect is not applied to button on real-time camera view

Tags: uivisualeffectview

I add blurred view on the button.
But only view with white(opacity is low) is added.

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blurView.frame = self.recordBtn.bounds
        recordBtn.addSubview(blurView)
```

What's the problem with Blur effect?

[image]